# XForms vs d3js - session expired, javascript error

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, xforms

Creating a topology building form:

[image]

Use XForm to set parameters, then - start d3js javascript to show topology graph.

```
<xf:trigger>
   <xf:label>Run JavaScript</xf:label>
    <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
            <xf:load resource="javascript:d3.json('{concat(instance('selected')/graph_uri/text(),instance('selected')/sel_vlan/text(),'&amp;conn_str=',instance('selected')/sel_connstr/text() )}',draw)" show="replace"/>
    </xf:action>
</xf:trigger>
```

The first run works well, but then I push the trigger in xform, I get message:

[image]

If I change selection in xf:repeater control - I get this error:

> Error  - Exception:  Object {javaClassName: "java.lang.Throwable",
>   message: "Error"}

```
throw 'allowScriptTagRemoting is false.';
(function(){
var r=window.dwr._[0];
//#DWR-INSERT
//#DWR-REPLY
r.handleException("8","0",{javaClassName:"java.lang.Throwable",message:"Error"});
})();
```

It looks like javascript does not return control to form...

Comment: Which XForms engine/processor are you using?

Comment: Not sure...I'm using eXistdb.
I've made a xquery  that generates html page with javascript command, and call it with xf:submission with replace="all" - works ok, but I have to refill form any time I need to build another graph

Comment: I doesn't look like Orbeon (which I work on), so can't help much.

Comment: Yes, it's not Orbeon - it's betterforms: [link](http://www.betterform.de/en/index.html)

Comment: Then maybe try their mailing-list.